# Mostrar tabla con PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Cuando corro en el servidor está vista sale bien pero a la hora de correr mi aplicación en un servidor local en esta vista me sale este error:

> DataTables warning: table id=data-table-basic - Ajax error.

Y lo necesito mostrar porque tengo que hacer un `dropdown` menú con la ultima columna de botones.

Este es mi `script` de la vista de la tabla que quiero mostrar, el `id` de mi tabla es **data-table-basic**, se supone que con este `script` mando a llamar el controlador que es para llenar mi tabla:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        //datatables
    table = $('#data-table-basic').DataTable({ 

    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.

    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('C_clients/ajax_listClients')?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },

    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],
});

    } );
```

Y este es mi controlador en el cual muestro a los clientes junto con 3 botones de opciones:

```
public function ajax_listClients()
{
    $list = $this->clients->get_datatables($this->session->userdata('idOriginatingSubscriber'));
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $clients) {
        /*$no++;*/
        $row = array();
        $options = "";
        /*$row[] = $no;*/
        $row[] = $clients->fcName;
        $row[] = $clients->fnId;
        $row[] = $clients->fcPhone;
        $row[] = $clients->fcEmail;
        $row[] = $clients->fcCity;
        $row[] = $clients->fcState;
        $row[] = date("m/d/Y" , strtotime($clients->fdRegisterDate));

        if($clients->fbActive == 1) { 
            $options = '<a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-success waves-effect" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title data-original-title="With Access"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i></span></a>';
        }else{ 
            $options = '<a href="" type="button" class="btn btn-warning waves-effect" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title data-original-title="No Access"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-download"></i></span></a>';
         }


        if ($this->session->userdata('idRole') == ROLE_ORIGINATING_SUBSCRIBER) {
            $options.= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:deleteClient('.$clients->fnId.')" type="button" class="btn btn-danger waves-effect" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title data-original-title='.$clients->fnId.'"><span><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></span></a>';
         }

        $row[] = '  
        <a href="'.site_url("C_clients/editClient/".$clients->fnId).'" type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title data-original-title="Edit"><span><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$options;
        $data[] = $row;

    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->clients->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->clients->count_filtered($this->session->userdata('idOriginatingSubscriber')),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

También intento hacer un `dropdown` menú en la ultima columna de la tabla y me sale error de sintaxis, pero reviso el código y según yo todo está bien.

Comment: No estás cerrando tu objeto `table`. Prueba así:  **`table = $('#data-table-basic').DataTable({ 

    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": []});`** OJO, no va una coma en la línea de `order`.

Comment: Se supone que lo cierro hasta después del ColumnDefs pero igual lo intenté como mencionas y me sale No data available  in table